# Calculating probabilities - is it joint or conditional?

Tags: probability

I have a problem like this:

> $P(A) = 0.2$
>
> $P(B|A) = 0.3$
>
> a) What is $P(\text{A and B})$
>
> b) Assume $P(B) = 0.4$. What's the probability that if $B$ happens, $A$ also happens?

For a) I found $P(\text{A and B}) = P(A) \times P(B|A) = 0.2 \times 0.3 = 0.06$

The wording in b) confuses me. So we know that $B$ happens with a probability of $0.4$ but how can I relate that now to $A$? My solution would have been to calculate $P(A) \times P(B)$ since there was no conditional property mentioned in b), but I wonder if this is too simple thinking?

Comment: In part b, they ask for $P(A|B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret "the probability that if $B$ happens, $A$ also happens" as "if know that $B$ happens, what is the probability that $A$ happens", i.e. $P(B|A)$ of which we can evaluate it as

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}P(B|A)$$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.